# POI,color row not working

Tags: java, apache, colors, row, apache-poi

```
 shouldn't this be working? fac is the uncolored workbook and facsheet is its uncolored sheet
```

sheet is the colored sheet,i'm trying to get the color from the workbook of one and set them into the other one

```
for(int i=2;rowIterator.hasNext();i++){
                      CellStyle style=fac.createCellStyle();
                      style.setFillForegroundColor(sheet.getRow(i).getRowStyle().getFillForegroundColor());
                      style.setFillBackgroundColor(sheet.getRow(i).getRowStyle().getFillBackgroundColor());
               facsheet.getRow(i).setRowStyle(style);

                  }
```

Answer (score 1):

How was the Excel spreadsheet where `sheet` comes from created?  Did you create it in Excel or POI?  If POI, did you use `setRowStyle`?

Usually, individual cells are styled, not entire rows, so [`getRowStyle()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getRowStyle%28%29) will return `null`.

Quoting the Javadocs from `Row#getRowStyle()`:

> Returns the whole-row cell styles. Most rows won't have one of these,
>   so will return null. Call isFormatted() to check first.

You will need to loop over all individual cells in each row, copying the `CellStyle` for each `Cell`.  But be careful, there is a limit to the number of `CellStyles` that can be created for a spreadsheet.  So if you already have created an identical `CellStyle`, then reuse it.

Comment: FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(str+""+".xls"));
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

            
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);